# Select an element by it's margin-left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin-left

So basically I have some div's and I need to select just the ones that don't have a margin-left set, or it's set to 0px.

Is there any way I can achieve this with jQuery ?

```
<div class="col col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 0px;"></div>
<div class="col col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 10px;"></div>
<div class="col col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 20px;"></div>
```

In this example I should select the first 2 div's because both of them have a  margin-left of `0px` (the first is not set but it's still `0px`);

PS. I prefer not to use a `for` for this operation.

Comment: `$whatYouWant = $('.col').filter(function() { return $(this).css('marginLeft') == '0px'; });`

Comment: Selecting elements by their margin-left value is a rather unusual request – can you explain what you want to achieve by this in the end? (Maybe there are other solutions.)

Comment: I want to create a custom bootstrap carousel, because the actual one don't gives the posibility to display 4 items on xs, 3 items on md, 2 items on sm and 1 item on xs and in the same time to be responsive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `filter()` to achieve this:

```
$('.col').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'), 10) == 0;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/0nxarbju/)

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks bro

Comment: No problem, glad to help.